# Scalar deleting error when deleting std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, oop, shared-ptr

I am trying to find out how can I delete children of my Block class. I tried to do it with raw pointer. I don't know why, but it didn't work. I was getting the scalar deleting error. I now tried to do this with std::shared_ptr. I t didn't work as well. I am removing the children with:

```cpp
void Block::remove(Block* block)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Block> ptr(block);
        auto it = std::find(children.begin(), children.end(), ptr);

        if (it != children.end())
        {
            *it = NULL;
            children.erase(it);
        }
    }
```

and the Block deleter is:

```cpp
Block::~Block()
    {
        for (auto& child : this->children)
        {
            child = NULL;
        }


        if (!this->children.empty())
            this->children.clear();
    }
```

According to the debugging process, the `ptr` variable is found and then deleted. At the point of deleting everything works well until the last line, where I am getting the scalar deletion error. Just for the record: the children variable is of type `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Block>>`.

EDIT:
The full code is here: https://github.com/DragonGamesStudios/Ages-of-Life. All the block functions are defined in AOLGuiLibrary/source/Block.cpp

Comment: Creating a shared pointer from whatever pointer was passed in as a parameter likely falls under "Bad Idea" (with the caps), but to get real help, you should provide a [mre].

Comment: You don't need an explicit destructor to destroy `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Block>>`. The one generated by a compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: @JaMiT Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Because your code effectively will call `delete block` at the end of `remove()`, @Sherlock.

Comment: @Evg I am getting the error even if I'm not manually deleting children, just a few lines later.

Comment: A [mre] should not rely on links to external sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `shared_ptr`s with raw pointers, and that is a bad practice. If I understand correctly, you store the blocks in the vector of shared pointers, and that means that this vector has an ownership on these objects. When you create an additional `shared_ptr` out of a raw pointer you create another object that has the ownership on the same object:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Block> ptr(block);
```

As the result, you would try to delete the object twice, and that leads to the undefined behavior.

First of all: do you need *shared* pointers? Consider using `unique_ptr` as a less error prone idea (if only one pointer object has the ownership, it is easier to understand who and when would destroy the underlying object).

Next, NEVER use raw pointers in this context: you may use raw pointers only when you don't store/delete the object. And for sure don't create smart pointers out of something that is already stored in one of them already.

Comment: Isn't shared_ptr designed for multiple owners?

Comment: It is designed to be created once from a raw pointer (or even better with the `make_shared` or `make_unique` call) and then it is just copied/moved/created from `unique_ptr`. Other patterns like creating shared pointer from `this` are more complicated and error-prone. Anyway, you must not wrap the same raw pointer into smart pointers twice.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes, to use that semantics, you need to make a copy of a shared pointer itself. If you pass just a raw pointer, how would a shared pointer know if there are other owners? A raw pointer is just a number, an address.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes they identified by counter within shared_ptr. While it possible to id an object uniquely by value of pointer, there is no standard solution of it (although some ECS systems do id objects by they address, one widely known game engine does, and in that situation such object cannot be an array or array's element)

Answer (score 0):

If `block` points at array code, this code is illegal, because for a `new[]` you have to call `delete[]`, and `std::shared_ptr<Block>` would call `delete`.  After that heap would be corrupted and further operations may fail. Same  happens if `blocks` points to an element of array. If `blocks` points to object not located in heap, it also would result in error.

In general it's bad idea to delete a pointer passed to a function. There is no guarantee that the pointer was one returned by new, and even if it was: by which new?

To create a strong reference counter for an array, you have to use `std::shared_ptr<Block[]>`, but usually it's better idea to use some kind of container.

To find a value of pointer object in array of shared pointers:

```
auto it =  std::find_if( children.begin(), children.end(), [=](auto& el) { 
                return el.get() == block; 
           });
```

If `children`is not static (that's not some kind of factory), then that destructor code is completely redundant. After call to `~Block()` there will be calls to destructors of every member of `Block`, including that collection  which would deallocate its  resources and call destructor to every pointer, which would call destructor to every `Block`.

Answer (score 0):

Once a pointer has been given to a shared_ptr, that shared_ptr *owns* it.  You must never again give that pointer to another shared pointer.

```
int * ptr = new int(1234);
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> shp1(ptr); // shp1 owns ptr
    std::shared_ptr<int> shp2(ptr); // shp2 owns ptr ???
}
// at this point ptr has been deleted twice
```

Note: it's preferable to not use `new` but to call std::make_shared and never give raw pointers to shared_ptr in the first place.

What you are doing to search for a child is exactly this problem.  Passing in a raw pointer, you create a new owner for it.  If that pointer is a child, it's already owned.  You *must not* create shared pointers from raw pointers after they have been given to a shared pointer.

Also, the destructor you showed for Block isn't wrong, but it is completely unnecessary.  All of what you coded there would happen automatically.  Block is destroyed, it destroys the vector it holds (so clearing it is unnecessary.)  The vector destroys its elements, so the shared pointers it holds are cleaned up too.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I agree (hence my "Note" under the example), but this is example code to make it clear that the same pointer is owned by two unrelated objects.